# How to create custom key bindings in draft.js?

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

I press `CTRL+B` => I want selected text bolded.

---

Useful links:

- http://facebook.github.io/draft-js/docs/advanced-topics-key-bindings.html#content - describes what `keyBindingFn` and `handleKeyCommand` do.
- https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/blob/master/examples/draft-0-10-0/rich/rich.html - lengthy example.
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0k9suXgCtTA - great video explaining how to add a button that will toggle boldness.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We need to pass two props to our `<Editor/>`:
`keyBindingFn`: maps `CTRL + some key` to some **action sting**
`handleKeyCommand`: gets passed this **action string** and decides what to do with it.

```js
import React from 'react';

import {
  Editor, EditorState,
  RichUtils, getDefaultKeyBinding
} from 'draft-js';


class Problem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { editorState: EditorState.createEmpty() };
  }

  // this function maps keys we press to strings that represent some action (eg 'undo', or 'underline')
  // then the this.handleKeyCommand('underline') function gets called with this string.
  keyBindingFn = (event) => {
    // we press CTRL + K => return 'bbbold'
    // we use hasCommandModifier instead of checking for CTRL keyCode because different OSs have different command keys
    if (KeyBindingUtil.hasCommandModifier(event) && event.keyCode === 75) { return 'bbbold'; }
    // manages usual things, like:
    // Ctrl+Z => return 'undo'
    return getDefaultKeyBinding(event);
  }

  // command: string returned from this.keyBidingFn(event)
  // if this function returns 'handled' string, all ends here.
  // if it return 'not-handled', handling of :command will be delegated to Editor's default handling.
  handleKeyCommand = (command) => {
    let newState;
    if (command === 'bbbold') {
      newState = RichUtils.toggleInlineStyle(this.state.editorState, 'BOLD');
    }

    if (newState) {
      this.setState({ editorState: newState });
      return 'handled';
    }
    return 'not-handled';
  }

  render = () =>
    <Editor
      editorState={this.state.editorState}
      onChange={(newState) => this.setState({ editorState: newState })}
      handleKeyCommand={this.handleKeyCommand}
      keyBindingFn={this.keyBindingFn}
    />
}
```

If you want something other than inline bold text (`RichUtils.toggleInlineStyle`), you can use `RichUtils.toggleBlockType`, `RichUtils.toggleCode`, [etc](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/blob/69890ed57b5f4256cc93ae8e9ea178296851a23e/docs/APIReference-RichUtils.md).

Comment: Good answer, but I believe the default `keyBindingFn` already handles this use case.

Comment: @natnai, true. changed to `CTRL+K => 'bbbold'` to avoid confusion.