# how to create custom key bindings (Ctrl+Enter) in draft js

Tags: reactjs, key-bindings, draftjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

I need to use Ctrl+Enter to call a function in Draft js

```
"draft-js": "^0.11.4",
"react-draft-wysiwyg": "^1.14.4",
```

So as in this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42311815/how-to-create-custom-key-bindings-in-draft-js) and [here](https://draftjs.org/docs/advanced-topics-key-bindings/) has mentioned, I wrote my code like this but it doesn't work well.

```
const  keyBindingFn = (event) => {
    if (KeyBindingUtil.hasCommandModifier(event) && event.keyCode === 13) { return callMyFunc(); }
    return getDefaultKeyBinding(event);
  }
```

The way I set it in Editor props:

```
return (
    <Editor
      editorState={editorState}
      onChange={(newState) => setEditorState(newState)}
      keyBindingFn={keyBindingFn}
    />
)
```

This function works for Ctrl+k or other keys.

An other way I tried  is like below it works and you can check it in
https://codepen.io/michael_cox/pen/xrvdRW?editors=1111
but for me it also doesn't work. maybe it's because of using draft-wysiwyg

```
const keyBindingFn = (event) => {
    if (event.keyCode === 13 && event.ctrlKey) {
         console.log('Ctrl+Enter');
    }
    return getDefaultKeyBinding(event);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const keyBindingFn = (event) => {
    if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 13) {
      if (event.nativeEvent.shiftKey) return console.log("event", event);
    }
    return getDefaultKeyBinding(event);
  };
```

Comment: Yes. Did you changed on both places?

Comment: I added my packages, I think it's because using draft-wysiwyg, do you have any idea

Comment: noticing the same bug in draft-wysiwyg. Looks like the library for some reason keeps the keyCode of ctrl if ctrl+enter is pressed.

Comment: [github-issue](https://github.com/jpuri/react-draft-wysiwyg/issues/1212) opened a thread hope they take a look.

Comment: @HamidShoja Decided to bypass the whole `keyBindingFn` for now and use the normal react document listener for now which seems to work. If you also look to solve the issue [so-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39355913/6262162)

Answer (score 0):

normally you can use the whole functionality from `draft-js` library.
`react-draft-wysiwyg` is just a wrapper over draft-js and it [src](https://github.com/jpuri/react-draft-wysiwyg/blob/f59ee8419cdbd45aab3bdfdf1995f112b09bbb6a/src/Editor/index.js) might help understand it more depth.
for instance, the `keyBindingFn` function has already been implemented there and if you add your own function with the same name it should be added at the end of the editor (spread rest of props and overriding should be included there as well)